# How can I make a div *not* expand to fill it's parent?

Tags: html, css, layout

I have a div wrapped around an image, like this:

```xml
<div class="containing-div">
      <div class="image-wrapper">
           <img src="image.jpg">
      </div>
      <div class="unrelated-stuff">
           Blah blah blah.
      </div>
</div>
```

Now, I expect `image-wrapper` to take the size of the image, and no more. But it doesn't; it instead fills to the height of `containing-div`. (See actual page here: http://holyworlds.org/new_hw/wallpapers.php )

My CSS is:

```css
.image-wrapper{
  float: left;
  box-shadow: inset 0px 4px 10px black;
  background-image: url('image.jpg');
}

.image-wrapper img{
  visibility: hidden;
}
.unrelated-stuff{
  float: left;
}
```

Now, it works just fine if I don't have a Doctype declared. But everything I've tried fails if I do.

How can I make `image-wrapper` be the size of the image while still using `<!doctype html>`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
.image-wrapper {
  display: inline;
}
```

Or:

```
.image-wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Or:

```
.image-wrapper {
  float: left;
}
```

Comment: float is not really the best option here... inline(-block) is much more appropriate.

Comment: Correction; all of these sorta work. They fix it's width, but for some reason not it's height. Look at the page, it's got float: left on. :)

Comment: Correction again: All of these work if I don't have a doctype declared. But they don't work with either the HTML5 or HTML4 doctype. :P

Answer (score 1):

CSS should be ...

```css
.image-wrapper
{
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
}
```

image-wrapper will automatically take on the width and height of the image unless you set the overflow property for image-wrapper.

Comment: @snostorm try and clear your history and cache and see if it works. You could also try and give the `.image-wrapper` class hard values. Make it like `.image-wrapper {width: 600; height: 200;}` I don't know what the values should actually be, but that's one alternet, but not as good of a method you could try. Its easier to just have it auto size it self to what its should be using the `.image-wrapper
{
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
}` the @bdparrish pointed out.

Comment: I get hung up on cached CSS all the time.

Comment: Tried that, doesn't change it. Hard values work, though the image size is variable so I'd have to use some Javascript. With width: 0, height: 0, it doesn't autosize; it just sets height and width to zero.