# Cant remove DIV margin

Tags: html, css

I have been playing around with a divider and its driving me crazy.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">


function ShowTimes() {
  var now = new Date();
  var hrs = 23-now.getHours();
  var mins = 59-now.getMinutes();
  var secs = 59-now.getSeconds();

      str = ('0'  + hrs).slice(-2)+':'+('0' + mins).slice(-2)+':'+('0' + secs).slice(-2);
  document.getElementById('countdownToMidnight').innerHTML = str;
}
var _cntDown;
function StopTimes() {
    clearInterval(_cntDown);
}

</script>
```

and it outputs the code when I enter the following code to body

```
<div id="countdownToMidnight"></div>
```

Problem is that it leaves an infinite margin to the right side (as wide as body allows)

I have tried the following things

```
width:100px;
margin: 0px;
float: left;
```

Float left is the only code that has actually enabled me to keep this script on the same line with my text, but with float - well it floats to the left and makes a mess out of my lander.

I want it to be next to the En Continu and before body text

```
<div class="conteneur_en_continu"><a href="#replaceme" class="tetiere">En Continu</a>


   <div id="countdownToMidnight" style="float:left;"></div>Until new points

</div>
```

What to do?

Comment: `display: inline` or `display: inline-block`

Comment: Thanks, it resolved the issue :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I make a div \*not\* expand to fill it's parent?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6238676/how-can-i-make-a-div-not-expand-to-fill-its-parent)

Comment: Of course, the other thing you could likely do is simply use a `<span>` instead of a div.